# how we add with loop value for multible select?

Tags: jquery, web

**

```
var val = {
                    01: { id: 01, text: 'Isis' },
                    02: { id: 02, text: 'Sophia' },
                    03: { id: 03, text: 'Alice' },
                    04: { id: 04, text: 'Isabella' },
                    05: { id: 05, text: 'Manuela' },
                    06: { id: 06, text: 'Laura' },
                    07: { id: 07, text: 'Luiza' },
                    08: { id: 08, text: 'Valentina' },
                    09: { id: 09, text: 'Giovanna' },
                    10: { id: 10, text: 'Maria Eduarda' },
                    11: { id: 11, text: 'Helena' },
                    12: { id: 12, text: 'Beatriz' },
                    13: { id: 13, text: 'Maria Luiza' },
                    14: { id: 14, text: 'Lara' },
                    15: { id: 15, text: 'Julia' }
                };
```

> += does not accept expression
>   , I want to do is dynamically retrieve the ID and the text information

```
                var UserFriends = "";
                var x = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < list.UserFriendIdList.length; i++) {
                    UserFriends+= {
                        x: { id: list.UserFriendIdList[i], text: list.UserFriendMailList[i] }

                    };
                    x++;
                }
```

> Print section
>
> ---
>
> `var pick = $("#pickList").pickList({ data: val });`

---

**
*how an arrangement should be made to take an assignment*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to either be spam or to poorly constructed to understand.

Comment: I don't know how the value is added with the loop I'm starting to use jQuery  @DelightedD0D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is not my primary coding language, but I'm pretty sure that a variable named `UserFriends` isn't going to work... because the capital lettered names are for class-names, not variables.

So this would mean something like:

```
var user_friends = "";
...
user_friends += ...
```

Secondly - you first declare `UserFriends` as a string `""` and then are adding part of a dictionary: `{ x: {id: ... }}` to it... these are two different things. You add strings to strings and dictionaries to dictionaries, not a combination of both.

So now it would be something like:

```
var user_friends = {};
...
user_friends += ...
```

Thirdly - `+=` isn't how you usually add entries to a dictionary. Instead you need to use a key eg: `user_friends[x]`

Try something like:

```
var user_friends = {};
...
user_friends[x] = { id: list.UserFriendIdList[i], text: list.UserFriendMailList[i] }
```

Fourthly... why do you use `i` as the loop-index... and then also manually increment `x` - surely `x == i` always, so use `i` instead?

```
var user_friends = {};
...
user_friends[i] = { id: list.UserFriendIdList[i], text: list.UserFriendMailList[i] }
```

(Note: my code has not been tested - these are ideas of how to understand what you need to do... bugfixing is up to you!)